# What causes SQL server to refresh plan cache?

Tags: sql-server, plan-cache

I am trying to understand situations that cause SQL server to refresh the plan cache.

For example:

1. SQL server restart
2. DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Is there a list of such things?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as refresh of the plan cache.

What can happen is that one more more plans are removed from cache. If a query that was removed is executed again in the future, then a new plan will be put in cache at that point.

Things that can remove plans from cache includes:

- Restart of instances (all plans, obviously, since the cache ceases to exist with the re-start)
- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (all plans, but can be limited depending on the options you specify)
- DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (depends on what options you specify)
- DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (all plans for that database)
- ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE CACHE (all plans for current database)
- Memory pressure (the plans that happened to be victim for the operation - the plan cache is a cache, after all)
- Some sp_configure settings will also clear the plan cache (see [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/09/sp_configure-options-clear-plan-cache/) post from Brent Ozar for more details).

[This](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/) is a blog post from Glenn Berry about some of the commands you can use the clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains situations that empty the plan cache.

There are some activities that invalidate the plan cache causing plans to be recompiled.

- schema changes
- statistics update